# Raspberry Pi - Python - joystick

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, joystick

I am using Raspberry Pi.

```
while True:
     if joystick.get_button(0) == 1:
           print ("stop")
     else
           print ("start")
```

The purpose of this code is :
         I want to interrupt some action while I press a button.

while running the code, it ignores me when I press the button and keep giving me "start". However, if I change the code to :

```
if joystick.get_button(0) == 0:
```

the program gives me "stop" at once. (0 is the default value of get_button(0), 1 means I press the button)

Comment: Have you tried looking at the actual value returned?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have a small example program downloaded from the internet, so I know it returns 1 when button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The cycle itself seems ok, so I would think that the problem is how your *get_button()* method acts. Be sure that it is returning the right value and that infinite loop and status checking are not running in the same thread.

Anyway, I would suggest you to use the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).
Basically, it allows you to create a reaction over your joystick button without using infinite loops.

The following code should fit your needs. Joystick class call methods from Player class every time the button is pressed, so every time Joystick change its state.

```
//OBSERVABLE OBJECT
class Joystick(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._button = 0
        self._observers = []

    def get_button(self):
        return self._button

    def set_button(self, value):
        for callback in self._observers:
            callback(self._button)

    def bind_to(self, callback):
        self._observers.append(callback)


//OBSERVER OBJECT
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        self._state = 0; //1 - stop, 0 - play
        self.controller.bind_to(self.change_state)

    def change_state(self, new_state):
        self_state = new_state
        if(new_state == 0)
            print 'play'
        else
            print 'stop'
```

This solution will print '*play*' and '*stop*' once, on every state change.
Then in your code you will create an observable instance:

```
joystick = new Joystick()
```

and pass it to an observer:

```
player = new Player(joystick)
```

in this way, when you launch your setter function:

```
joystick.set_button(0)
```

joystick will automatically change the status in player instance.